# How to convert response to another type before it handled by MessageConverter in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

For example, here's a method which returns a `User`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/user")
public User getUser() {
    return new Users();
}
```

For some reasons, the client expect an other type

```
class CommonResponse<T> {
  int code;
  T data;
}
```

So I need to convert all return value from `T`(`User` for this e.g.) to `CommonResponse<T>` before it handled by the `MessageConverter`.

Cause there're many request hanlders should be modified, is there any way to write the convert data just once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find [ResponseBodyAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html) to do such work.

Here the sample code:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class CommonAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return returnType.getDeclaringClass().getPackage().getName().startsWith("foo.bar.demo");
        // you can change here to your logic
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        return new CommonResponse<Object>().setCode(200).setData(body);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add/configure your custom converter. so that your custom converter is executed before others

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "org.app.web" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
      List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        messageConverters.add(createCustomConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
    private HttpMessageConverter<Object> createCustomConverter() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be necessary instead of extending ResponseBodyAdvice as in the other answer, since the advice is allowed to change the response body entity but not the `returnType`, breaking some message converters (e.g. GsonHttpMessageConverter with parameterised types).